# About Openshift Bandwidth - Have limits?

Tags: openshift

I have a question about Openshift... I read the prices table comparsion and does not mention bandwidth limit...

OpenShift don't have bandwidth limits, like Google App Engine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift Online does not currently publish any public bandwidth usage limitations, however, I am sure that on the free plan you would be expected to stay within some reasonable limits.  You might get a better explanation by using the contact form here: https://developers.openshift.com/contact as this is not really a good question for StackOverflow.